# Functions return error messages only when imported

Tags: python, function, import

I'm conducting some data analysis for energy consumption, and have written the below functions within the file data_inputs.py to assist.

```
elec_kWh = 50000
gas_MJ = 0
coal_kg = 0
oil_L = 0

#%% sum energy consumption
def elec_MJ(elec_kWh):
        elec_MJ = (elec_kWh * 3.6)
        return elec_MJ

def coal_MJ(coal_kg):
        coal_MJ = (coal_kg * 22.1)
        return coal_MJ

def oil_MJ(oil_L):
        oil_MJ = (oil_L * 38.6)
        return oil_MJ

#%% sum energy consumption
def total_energy_consumption_MJ(elec_kWh, gas_MJ, coal_kg, oil_L):
        total_consumption = (elec_MJ(elec_kWh)+
                                gas_MJ +
                                coal_MJ(coal_kg) +
                                oil_MJ (oil_L)
                                )
        return total_consumption

print (total_energy_consumption_MJ(elec_kWh, gas_MJ, coal_kg, oil_L))

def elec_percent_cons(
                        elec_kWh, 
                        gas_MJ, 
                        coal_kg, 
                        oil_L
                        ):
        elec_percent_cons = (
                                elec_MJ(elec_kWh) / 
                                total_energy_consumption_MJ(elec_kWh, gas_MJ, coal_kg, oil_L)
                                )
        return elec_percent_cons
```

I'm looking to import these data input functions into a data outputs file with more sophisticated data modelling.

When I run this function within data_inputs.py, it works perfectly. But when I try and import elec_percent_cons into a data_outputs.py file, I get the following error:

```
from data_inputs import elec_kWh, gas_MJ, coal_kg, oil_L, total_energy_consumption_MJ, elec_percent_cons

     12 
     13 def elec_MJ(elec_kWh):
---> 14         elec_MJ = elec_kWh * 3.6
     15         return elec_MJ
     16 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'float'
```

I'm confused as to how this could be happening - I've confirmed that the function prints a value in data_inputs.py, and that it imports the float value of elec_kWh into the function. I don't understand how it could be interpreting the elec_kWh value as a function?

Comment: you're passing a function to `elec_MJ` instead of a number.

Comment: ^ Agreed. I'm struggling to see where the mistake takes place. It doesn't help that your functions assign to variables with the same name as the functions which is a bit confusing on the eye. I would just return directliy like "return elec_kWh * 3.6"

Comment: Actually, this code works for me as is. I just tested importing it into a file and it works. There has to be something else that wasn't shared here which is breaking it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrote the functions and found an errant line that was messing me up. Resolved.

Comment: Please add updated code as well to support your answer. So  that, if someone else face this, could understand what the issue was.

Comment: Please do not post answers like this. You can rather comment or post complete answer with code.